# Does domain restriction need to be written for this integral

Tags: calculus

I have the following integral and I worked it out as follows:
$$
\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-x}}
$$

$$
2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}} d u
$$

$$
2 \sin ^{-1}(\sqrt{x})+c
$$

I am getting mixed up when I need to list the domain restriction for these types of integrals.  Do I need to include it in my work?

$$x>0$$

Comment: The domain of $\frac1{\sqrt x\sqrt{1-x}}$ is $x\in(0,1)$, so your answer should technically also have this domain restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int \frac1{\color{red}{\sqrt{x}}\color{blue}{\sqrt{1-x}}}dx$$

For $\color{blue}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ in blue  $1-x >0$

But, for $\color{red}{\sqrt{x}}$ in red color $x > 0$

Otherwise, The answer of integral $\sin^{-1}$ exists for only $x \in [-1, 1]$ but we know we can't take $x$ greater than one for blue part$\sqrt{1-x}$ and also greater than zero for red part $ \sqrt x$

So, $x \in (0, 1)$  here we exclude $1$